# How to correctly create a data masking policy?

Tags: oracle

I have created a Full Redaction Policy for a column of my table, it works fine and hides the information, but it also does it in my application ... how can I make the distinction so that it only masks outside the application?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something that identifies "coming from the app".  The most common example of this would be a context variable, eg

```
expression => q'{sys_context('USERENV','MACHINE')='MYAPPSERVER'}'
```

either with the standard USERENV context, or a custom context of your own making

Comment: Thank you! just what I needed, use the HOST parameter and the name of my server